# Why do we watch X, but listen to Y?

Tags: grammar

Why do we "watch" something, but "listen to" something? For example, "watch a movie", but "listen to a broadcast".

Comment: Interesting question, but I think it needs to be refined a little bit. What do you mean by "why"? What type of explanation are you looking for ("how did this come to be," or "how can the difference be explained in an easy-to-remember way")?

Comment: And why do we "look at" X, but "hear" Y?

Comment: I'm not sure this will help you but in German the word listen takes two prepositions, and both of those are for attention which needs to be directed.  I'm not sure (which is why I'm using the comment section) but I think English followed this.  Not sure about "watch" yet.

Comment: Because watch and listen describe completely different actions, "watch" is done by the eyes while "listen" is done by ears. Just because broadcast might mean video on tv as well as audio only transmission from a radio doesn't make watch and listen any similar to each other than look and hear. We certainly wouldn't say watch the radio or listen to a film

Answer (score 8):

Such are the rules of grammar. In this case *listen* requires the preposition "to" with an  object, while *watch* (as in "watch a show") must be used without a preposition.

**This is simply the way the language developed over time.** In modern English, *listen* is intransitive and takes a prepositional object. However, in Shakespearean times this was not the case:

> Listen /transitive verb/ 
>   archaic : to give ear to : hear
>
> *lady, vouchsafe to **listen what I say** — Shakespeare*

(Webster's Unabridged)

Edit: Here's an excerpt from *The works of Thomas Hearne* that I liked, which demonstrates this use of *listen*:

[image]

([Courtesy of Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=Iv8pAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=%22How%20he%20betraied%20my%20lord.%22&source=bl&ots=HdnCjE996f&sig=hZFBpS4Yb4-1PjEXi-WvvPBSyK4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAWoVChMItLjakf_ayAIVSmkUCh1V_wM3#v=onepage&q&f=false))

Comment: If one used *look* rather than *watch* then the preposition *at* would be required, corresponding with *listen to*, since *look* in this sense is also intransitive.

Comment: I think giving the Shakespeare quote is a bit shakey, given that this was written in iambic pentameter and adding "to" breaks this.  Do you have any other sources?

Comment: Also, "watch" can take a preposition: "He watched for intruders."

Comment: @michael_timofeev Of course "watch" can take the preposition "for", but this would change the meaning and wouldn't fit OP's example. "Listen" can also take a preposition as in "listen up", but that's obviously different.

Comment: Well, you first sentence says watch must be used without a preposition...so I'm not sure what you mean.  Also, watch for something IS similar to listen to something in that attention is being directed.

Comment: I am interested in the Elizabethan point of view on this.  Perhaps you can look up some more examples?

Comment: @michael_timofeev I meant "watch" doesn't take a preposition in the OP's example, of course. Made it more clear in the answer, thanks.

Comment: @michael_timofeev Take a look at this Middle English entry: http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=byte&byte=224649874&egdisplay=open&egs=224788218 ("Ȝowre cumandment I sal fulfill, If ȝe wil **listen me** untill, With hertes and eres understandes.")

Comment: that was an entry for Understood.  Where is the "listen" part?

Comment: @michael_timofeev I included another example in my updated answer.

Comment: @michael_timofeev I provided a whole sentence, just hit Ctrl-F and search for it on the page. It demonstrates the usage of "listen" in context.

Comment: Well, if you're right about listen not taking "to" in old English that makes things a bit more complicated (but a bit easier for a theory I am researching.)

Comment: @michael_timofeev In Old English the verb was *hlystan*. Consider: *"Hie habbaS Moysen and witegan; **hie hlysten him.**"*, which translates to *"They have Moses and the Prophets; let them listen to them"*, Luke 16:29"

Answer (score 0):

It certainly depends on the context.

You don't always listen to a [braodcast](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/broadcast) as it can mean both radio and TV broadcast as defined in [Merriam-Webster]:

> made public by means of radio or television

You can watch a broadcast.

***Watch*** is a [transitive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transitive) verb ***that doesn't require a preposition*** while ***listen*** is an ***intransitive*** verb that requires a preposition to have an object.

"Transitive" means:

> characterized by ***having or containing a direct object***.

[Merriam-Webster]

Answer (score -1):

Some verbs are called "prepositional verbs" and require a preposition between the verb and its direct object. Granted this is descriptive and not prescriptive, but that is just the way it is. Cheers.